# Why did this symbol/pattern appear to Batman in Gotham?

Tags: dc, dc-extended-universe, justice-league-2017

Having just seen the 2017 Justice League only once, I may have missed a detail, but one thing bothered me throughout the movie:

When Batman is on the roof in Gotham city, he

> kills one of Steppenwolf's parademons. The gore leaves behind a pattern resembling the 3 mother boxes. I'm not sure what would have caused its splatter marks to form that shape though. Is it formed in their armor? Is Steppenwolf's power to create them related to the mother boxes in a way that might make a magical little poof in that shape when they die? Is it some manifestation of the soul of the mother boxes?

I understand the significance of the pattern as an obvious clue for Bruce Wayne, and more importantly us, but I'm wondering if there is any possible in-universe explanation for how that pattern appeared at that time in Gotham.

Comment: I was wondering the same. IIRC, it is said later in the movie that Batman also knows about the motherboxes from Lex Luthor's notes. So the clue was not necessary

Comment: A few things in that scene let me think that it was part of a reshoot, among else the fact that a pursuit start and ends in exactly the same place for no reasons. Like the set was really limited. If this is confirmed, it might (out of universe) have been added to ensure that the viewer understands the importance of the boxes.

Comment: @Taladris: The clue was necessary because although Bruce had info on the boxes from the notes it was important to establish that it was something happening *now*. Otherwise lex's notes could have just been theoretical stuff that would never have any relevance.

Comment: Because terrible writing

Comment: @Valorum I hate that answer, though you are almost certainly right. I'm not even close to a DC expert though, so maybe someone could enlighten me.

Answer (score 6):

From the [Mother Box Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mother_Box) it states:

> Mother Boxes can access the energy of the Source for various effects;

Some of these effects include, but are not limited to:

> rearrange molecular structure of matter

and

> manipulate the life-force of a host to sustain it past fatal injuries,...and do many other things

From this information it can be inferred that the parademons life-forces are linked to the three Mother Boxes on Earth. The destruction of the host containing the Mother Box energy can leave residual traces of the three linked Box's energy, and under the right circumstances, cause such a pattern to be created.